# Share style (css, images) in multiple projects in .Net Core

Tags: layout, .net-core

I am using the same layout and styles - css and images and other resources - for multiple web projects in .Net Core. Does anyone have any ideas on how to separate these elements outside of the projects? I would like to share the same resources in multiple projects without duplicating these files.

Comment: Can you define "style" in this context? Do you mean they projects all use a similar set of conventions and names for builds and build configuration?

Comment: @omajid I am refering to set of css files and images

Comment: I have resolved this issue creating a hard symlink to the other CSS files and images on every project